# Canvas and Stroke Alignment in D3/vega

Tags: d3.js, svg, canvas, vega

Is there any way to set stroke alignment (I need it to be "inset" so that strokes for two adjacent shapes won't overlap) in D3 canvas, or, even better, Vega?

Comment: There isn't. Move the shapes so they don't overlap instead.

Comment: too bad; moving does not help, especially in the case with geopolygons